# Kernel triple-faults after calling function

Tags: assembly, crash, kernel, nasm

I have two functions running in a Kernel, function A and function B. Function A clears the screen and passes control to Function B (which currently does nothing). When control is returned to Function A, a triple-fault occurs. (This is x86 Intel syntax)

---

### Function A

```
function_a:
pop edx
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 8
push dword 0
pop eax
mov [ebp-4], eax
jmp .il_15
.il_7:
push dword 753664
mov eax, [ebp-4]
push eax
pop eax
pop ebx
add eax, ebx
push eax
push dword 0
pop eax
pop ebx
mov [ebx],al
mov eax, [ebp-4]
push eax
push dword 1
pop eax
pop ebx
add eax, ebx
push eax
pop eax
mov [ebp-4], eax
.il_15:
mov eax, [ebp-4]
push eax
push dword 4000
pop eax
pop ebx
cmp ebx, eax
jl .il_7
push dword 4
call function_b
jmp .methodend
.methodend:
add esp, 8
pop ebp
push edx
ret
```

---

### Function B

```
function_b:
pop edx
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 4
jmp .methodend ;This is just an empty function
.methodend:
add esp, 4
pop ebp
push edx
ret
```

---

I'm pretty sure I have the stack set up properly for each function (pop return value, push ebp etc.) so I'm not sure what's causing the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in `function_b` or `function_a` appears to clean up the word pushed onto the stack just before calling `function_b`:

```
push dword 4
call function_b
```

Also, `function_b` trashes `edx` which is being used to store the return address from `function_a`.

I'm not sure why the functions have the pattern of popping the return address into `edx` so that it can be pushed back on just before returning - why not just leave the return address on the stack altogether? If you don't want to do this, then you'll need to save `edx` before calling `function_b` (maybe by pushing it onto the stack) and restore it afterward.

Comment: I inserted `add esp, 4` after the call, but it still triple-faulted

Comment: Ah! I'm silly. I'll change the return address things then XD.